# Use Github Release model to host application's Sparkle appcast

Tags: xcode, github, rss, release, sparkle

Can Github's Release feature be used to host an application's Sparkle appcast (RSS feed)?  The goal is to eliminate the need to have another server involved to support application updates.

The challenge would be that the file's URL (referenced by an Xcode project's SUFeedURL property) wouldn't be consistent across versions:

- https://github.com/user/foobar/releases/tag/v0.1.0
- https://github.com/user/foobar/releases/tag/v0.2.0

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't yet found a way to integrate the appcast directly with GitHub Releases, I've been using GitHub Pages to host the appcast to avoid the need for another server, as you said.  It also looks like [releases.io](http://releases.io) might help with creating a release notes link for Sparkle from the GitHub Releases.